# Append a suffix to each regex match in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to append " Smith" to every name mapped to a spirit animal.

```
import re

contents = '''
  var cool_spirit_animals = {
    'Abel': 'unicorn',
    'Bob': 'lion'
  };

  var spirit_plants = {
    'Cain': 'venus fly trap'
  };

  var stupid_spirit_animals = {
    'Dan': 'lamprey'
  };

  var spirit_vampires = {
    'Emily': 'Buffy',
    'Fred': 'Dracula'
  };
'''

my_regex = r'(spirit_animals = \{[\n\r\s]*\'\w+)(\': [^\}]*)'
print re.sub(my_regex, r'\1 Smith\2', contents)
```

but my regex only changes the first name in every animals mapping. The script prints:

```
  var cool_spirit_animals = {
    'Abel Smith': 'unicorn',
    'Bob': 'lion'
  };

  var spirit_plants = {
    'Cain': 'venus fly trap'
  };

  var stupid_spirit_animals = {
    'Dan Smith': 'lamprey'
  };

  var spirit_vampires = {
    'Emily': 'Buffy',
    'Fred': 'Dracula'
  };
```

'Bob' didn't change - only 'Abel ' changed. How can I write a regex that appends `Smith` to **all** names with spirit animals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first match the `spirit_animal` block and then add `Smith` to the names inside a callback method to the `re.sub`:

```
def repl(m):
    return re.sub(r"'(\w+)':", r"'\1 Smith':", m.group())

my_regex = r'spirit_animals\s*=\s*\{[^}]*(?:}(?!;(?:$|\n))[^}]*)*};(?:$|\n)'
print re.sub(my_regex, repl, contents)
```

See the [code demo](http://ideone.com/FADDNQ)

The `spirit_animals\s*=\s*\{[^}]*(?:}(?!;(?:$|\n))[^}]*)*};(?:$|\n)` regex exatracts the `spirit_animals` block (note it is an unrolled version of `(?s)spirit_animals\s*=\s*\{.*?};(?:$|\n)` regex). The `'(\w+)':` matches the names inside that block.

Comment: I never knew that `sub` took a handler for each match. Thank you!

Comment: Let's live and learn :). It is actually a nice workaround for a `\G` operator that is missing in Python regex.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by that. `\G` anchors a match in perl, right? How does allowing a handler mimic `\G`?

Comment: I think you can understand it better using an illustration: [`(?:spirit_animals\s*=\s*\{|(?!^)\G)\s*'\K([^']+)('\s*:\s*'[^']+',?)` => `$1 Smith$2`](https://regex101.com/r/lB3cZ3/1). `\G` matches either the beginning of a string or the empty location (string) after the previous successful match.